# how to find the deleted branches in remote repo

Tags: git

I am looking to find a command which can be run from git bash to find the branches which are deleted from remote. The below command is working for one repo but not the other.

```
git branch -v|grep \\[gone\\]|awk '{print $1}'
```

I am unable to see the deleted branch even after deleting the same from the bit bucket remote repository URL. The above command is working for one repo but not for others.
I don't want to delete the branches , just need to know which all branches are deleted from remote repository.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be an unimportant detail but let's try to at least rule it out : you're assuming `gone` will be preceded by a `[`, which is only the case for the output of `git branch -v`, not `git branch -vv`. Could it be a difference in the output of `git branch -v` between git versions, or maybe configs?

Comment: What's the output of `git branch -v` in the repositories where the command _doesn't_ work?

Comment: I tried using git branch -v and git branch -vv. In both cases, GONE keyword is not shown for the repository. I suspect it might be some config issue. Also, I am seeing a strange thing in GIT PULL, even if I do git pull it will again pulling the same branches for the second time  and popualting message "already up to date".  Is there any other way I can check if the remote branch is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I thinnk you are looking for a specific git command:

```
git reflog
```

This shows you what happened to your repository in the past including all deleted branches. If your repository is huge you can use grep to filter its output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using git reflog|grep -i <branch-name> but it didn't gave me any information even when I deleted the branch --> git pull.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Run:

```
git fetch --prune
```

(which can be abbreviated to `git fetch -p` if you prefer), or:

```
git remote origin prune
```

These should both do the same thing, but in some versions of Git (I can't remember which ones except that they were fairly old, maybe 1.8-ish era) one of the two has a bug that fails to prune some remote-tracking names.

#### Long-ish

When you run `git fetch`, your Git:

- calls up another Git, typically at some internet URL
- has that Git list out all of its branch names (and other names) and the commit hash IDs that go with them;
- check to see if that other Git has commits that you don't have, that you want;
- gets those commits from the other Git; and, last,
- creates or updates *remote-tracking names* for some or all of the branch names the other Git listed.

(The "some or all" in the last part accounts for the fact that some ways of running `git fetch` limit how many names your Git asks for and/or looks-at.  We won't use these here, but note that if you have set up a single-branch clone, you have asked your Git to *default* to only looking at that one name.  I will assume here that you have not set up a single-branch clone.<sup>1</sup>)

The problem here is simple enough.  Suppose that on Monday, you run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, and your Git calls up a Git at some GitHub URL or whatever.  *Their* Git, at this time, has three branches: `master`, `feature/a`, and `feature/b`.  So *your* Git creates or updates your `origin/master`, your `origin/feature/a`, and your `origin/feature/b`.

Now it's Tuesday, and you run `git fetch` again.  Your Git calls up their Git and they're down to just `master` because both features have been merged.  So your Git gets any new commits needed and then updates your `origin/master`.  There is no `feature/a`; there is no `feature/b`; so your Git *does nothing with these two names that don't exist*.  Your `origin/feature/a` is left alone, and your `origin/feature/b` is left alone.

You now have two stale remote-tracking names!

You could manually delete them:

```
 git branch -r -d origin/feature/a origin/feature/b
```

but it is a lot more convenient to have your Git recognize that, gee, it must have *created* `origin/feature/a` and `origin/feature/b` on its own, so maybe it should *delete* them on its own now too.  The `--prune` option does exactly that: it takes the full list that they gave you, and uses that to whittle away any remote-tracking names that must be left over from earlier.

---

<sup>1</sup>To find out, run:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

If this prints the single line:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

you have a standard, everyday setup.  If not, you may have a single-branch clone; at the very least, you set up something unusual.

---

#### You can set up pruning as your default

Using:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

you can tell Git that you want `git fetch` to *default* to `git fetch --prune` *for all your repositories* (that's the `--global` part).  Or, leave out the `--global` to set this setting for one particular repository.

The only drawback I know of, which is quite slight, is that if someone accidentally deletes some branch on `origin`, and you have this option set and run `git fetch origin`, your Git deletes your remote-tracking name, which you *could* have used earlier to restore the *branch* name in the Git at `origin`.  In other words, it changes your setup so that you are less able to rescue other people who did something dumb.  If rescuing others is not high on your to-do list, that's pretty minor.

Comment: Question says: “I don't want to delete the branches , just need to know which all branches are deleted from remote repository.” You are deleting them.

Comment: @matt: I'm deleting the remote-tracking names in his repository, which he needs to have happen so that his `git branch -v` output will include the `gone` text. (Another option is to use `git ls-remote origin` and inspect the output, but that's much more human-intensive.)

Comment: I see! Sort of. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! My git bash version is 2.18.0.windows.1. I ran the command  git remote prune origin --dry-run but it shows me the branches which still exist in remote repository. I am publishing a report and want to know if the branches are deleted from remote repository but do not want delete the branches if it is merged.

Comment: @RahulRaj: with `--dry-run`, `git fetch` doesn't actually *do* anything, it only prints out what it *would* do. Remember, *your branches are not their branches:* your Git has *its own* branches, and their Git has its. Your Git's *remote-tracking names* (`origin/*`) are your Git's *copy* of their Git's *branches* and these are what `git fetch` updates. Without `--prune`, your `git fetch` leaves stale remote-tracking names behind in your own repository.